# Elasticsearch exception (failed to create query: invalid range: from (95) cannot be > to (93))

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query for finding all record witch have phone number, and it works for me

```
PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = '\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})'

{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "biography": {
        "value": PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to do the same, but with email regex.
I use uax_url_email for my biography field. So, I think that I have corrects tokens with '@' symbol

When I use next query, I have error

```
EMAIL_REGEX = '[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1}\@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{1}'

{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "biography": {
        "value": EMAIL_REGEX
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
I have no idea what it is means `"reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: invalid range: from (95) cannot be > to (93)"`

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it was wrong regex

Need use next: `EMAIL_REGEX = '[a-zA-Z.\_\-]{1}\@[a-zA-Z0-9.\_\-]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{1}'`